# Anonymous Union in Struct Initializer

Tags: c, struct, initialization, unions

Why does following example not work in C?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  int x;
} X;

typedef struct {
  char y[10];
} Y;

typedef struct {
  int pos;
  union {
    X x;
    Y y;
  };
} Test;

int main() {
  X x = { 65 };
  Y y = { "Hallo" };
  Test t = { 1, x }; // OK
  printf("1: %d %d '%s'\n", t.pos, t.x.x, t.y.y);
  Test t2 = { 2, y }; // ERROR
  printf("2: %d %d '%s'\n", t2.pos, t2.x.x, t2.y.y);
  Test t3 = { 3 }; // OK
  printf("3: %d %d '%s'\n", t3.pos, t3.x.x, t3.y.y);
  return 0;
}
```

> main.c: In function ‘main’:
>   main.c:25:3: error: incompatible types when initializing type ‘int’ using type ‘Y’
>      Test t2 = { 2, y }; // ERROR
>      ^

EDIT: 
By the way: `t2.y = y;` works

Comment: Test t2 = { 2, y : y }; seems to work in gcc

Comment: struct definitions should not be typedef'd.  the typedef only clutters the code, leads to misunderstandings for the human reader, and clutters the compiler name space

Comment: having the only difference between a type name and an instance name being the capitalization is a very good source of bugs that are very hard to find.   BTW: when writing an initialization string, all values must be constants and struct y is NOT a constant.

Comment: @user3629249 Whether to typedef structs or not is a subjective style matter. There are two camps: the Linux camp, who think that they shouldn't be typedef:ed, and the everyone-else-camp who think they should. There's no obvious right or wrong here, so please don't start a style debate in comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the initializer's type isn't analyzed and matched against the possible members of the `union`.

Instead, you're simply supposed to provide an initializer for the first `union` member.

C11 draft §6.7.9.17:

> Each brace-enclosed initializer list has an associated current object. When no designations are present, subobjects of the current object are initialized in order according to the type of the current object: array elements in increasing subscript order, structure members in declaration order, and the first named member of a union.

As mentioned, you can use designators to control this:

```
Test t2 = { 2, .y = y };
```

should work (that `.y` is a designator, "new" in C99).

Comment: So it should be noted that this problem isn't related to anonymous structs/unions as such, but merely plain union initialization. And since anonymous structs/unions require C11, designated initializers will work fine.

Answer (score 4):

You have to specify that you are initializing a member other than the first:

```
 Test t2 = { 2, { .y = y } } ;
```

Otherwise the compiler will try to initialize it as if you wrote: `.x = y`